# WiX 'Bundle' 'ExePackage' 'DetectCondition' is always false

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, bundle, bootstrapper

I am trying to create a WiX bundle that installs the .NET Framework 4.0 before my [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installer. I inspected the log file for my bootstrapper using the command line argument `\l log.txt` and discovered that the `ExePackage::DetectCondition` is always evaluating to false.

I am including `WixNetFxExtension.dll` as a reference in my Visual Studio 2010 Windows Installer XML Bootstrapper project.

I am including the `NetFxExtension` namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
    xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
    xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
```

Providing the basic bundle framework:

```
  <Bundle Name="RSA Bootstrapper"
      ...
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
      ...

    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NET40" />
      <PackageGroupRef Id="RSA_Application" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
    ...
```

I am including the `<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL" />` in the fragment and then going on to define the ExePackage for .NET Framework 4.0 (`NET40`):

```
  <Fragment>
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL" />
    <PackageGroup Id="NET40">
    <ExePackage SourceFile="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
        Compressed="yes"
        Cache="yes"
        DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"
        InstallCommand="/norestart /passive /showrmui /ACTION=Install"
        Permanent="yes"
        InstallCondition="NOT NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"
        Vital="yes" >
    <ExitCode Value="0" Behavior="success" />
    <ExitCode Value="1641" Behavior="scheduleReboot" />
    <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="scheduleReboot" />
    <ExitCode Behavior="error" /> <!-- Everything else is an error -->
  </ExePackage>
    ...
```

I have also checked the Visual Studio build output to confirm that the `WixNetFxExtension.dll` is referenced correctly:

C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\Light.exe ... -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\WixNetFxExtension.dll"

The problem is with the `DetectCondition` property. No matter what I set it to, it evaluates to `false`.

Thinking that maybe the `NETFRAMEWORK40FULL` reference cannot be trusted, I tried using this instead:

```
<Fragment>
  <Variable Name="isInstalled"
      Type="numeric"
      Value="0"
      Persisted="yes"
      bal:Overridable="yes"/>
  <util:RegistrySearch Id="FindInstallKey"
      Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
      Value="Install"
      Result="exists"
      Variable="InstallKeyExists" />
  <util:RegistrySearch
      Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
      Value="Install"
      Variable="isInstalled"
      After="FindInstallKey"
      Condition="InstallKeyExists = true"
      Format="raw" />
</Fragment>
```

Setting `DetectCondition="isInstalled"` or `DetectCondition="isInstalled = true"` always evaluates to false. Even setting `DetectCondition="true"` always evaluates to false!

Here is a log snippet of what I am talking about, with `DetectCondition="true"`

```
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i001: Burn v3.7.1224.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Users\lalic\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RSA Preset\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\Bootstrapper.exe, cmdline: '/l log.txt -burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{33090847-CC78-445B-BAAA-564B840B7E8E} {38F95C6A-EC0F-4402-951B-FABFC5827CB6} 6296'
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\lalic\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RSA Preset\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\log.txt'
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\lalic\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RSA Preset\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\Bootstrapper.exe'
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i052: Condition '((VersionNT = v5.1) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 3)) OR ((VersionNT = v5.2) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 2)) OR ((VersionNT = v6.0) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 1)) OR (VersionNT >= v6.1)' evaluates to true.
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'RSA Bootstrapper'
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i052: Condition 'true' evaluates to false.
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i103: Detected related package: {D431417D-F0AC-4CFB-8E25-E27F5B8101D9}, scope: PerMachine, version: 2.1.15.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i101: Detected package: dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe, state: Absent, cached: None
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i101: Detected package: RSA_Preset.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:01:43]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:02:04]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
[16A0:17B4][2013-02-13T13:02:04]i052: Condition 'NOT NETFRAMEWORK40FULL' evaluates to true.
```

Specifically,
`i052: Condition 'true' evaluates to false.`
and actually `Condition 'NOT NETFRAMEWORK40FULL' evaluates to true.` even though I have .NET 4.0 Full installed and can manually find the .NET 4.0 entry in my registry, both in the usual spot and under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` (I am on a 64 bit system).

Am I missing something? Why doesn't DetectCondition work for me? The project compiles, runs, deploys the payload(s) and otherwise works fine.

Comment: Apologize for the long post. Trying to be thorough! And on that note, I am using WiX v3.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL" />` is a reference to an MSI property but you're creating a bundle. Bundles have variables that are distinct from MSI properties, though Burn itself provides a number of bundle variables that mimic those that MSI provides.

That said, WixNetFxExtension provides package groups for the 4.0 NetFx installers. You can replace all that with a simple `<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist" />`.

Comment: Huh. I did not realize `NETFRAMEWORK40FULL` was an MSI property. Thanks. Maybe that is causing the logic error? Still haven't figured that part out, although `NetFx40Redist` avoids that issue altogether. Any thoughts on this?

I shied away from using `<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist" />` because I wanted to control the installation attributes of the package. I decided to stop being stubborn and give it a shot (at your suggestion) and so far it is working out for me; I guess the default settings are fine.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Yes, you can't use an MSI property in a Burn expression. That requires a Burn variable.

Comment: The fact that "Bundle" variables can't be used in MSIs makes no sense whatsoever. Why even have them?

Answer (score 3):

Variables like NETFRAMEWORK40FULL are MSI variables, you cannot use them in Bundles.

I have successfully embedded the .NET Framework 4.0 Client Version within my bundle. Conditions variables resolved from the Registry.

Notice the syntax `"&lt;&lt;"` (which translates to <<) in DetectCondition attribute. This page may help http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
    xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" 
    xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
    xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

    <Bundle
        Name="My Program Name"
        Version="1.2.0"
        Manufacturer="SUSU"
        UpgradeCode="some-guid">

        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4"/>
            <MsiPackage Id="MyProgramInstaller" SourceFile="product.msi" Compressed="yes"/>
        </Chain>

        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
                LicenseFile="license.rtf"
                ShowVersion="yes"
            />
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    </Bundle>

    <Fragment>

        <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client" Value="Version" 
            Variable="Netfx4ClientVersion" /> 

        <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client" Value="Version" 
            Variable="Netfx4x64ClientVersion" Win64="yes" /> 

        <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" 
            Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" /> 

        <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" 
            Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion" Win64="yes"/> 


        <PackageGroup Id="Netfx4">
            <ExePackage
                Id="Netfx4"
                Cache="no"
                Compressed="yes"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Vital="yes"
                SourceFile="c:\Downloads\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe"
                InstallCommand="/q"
                DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion &lt;&lt; &quot;4&quot;) OR (Netfx4ClientVersion &lt;&lt; &quot;4&quot;) OR (Netfx4x64ClientVersion &lt;&lt; &quot;4&quot;) OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion &lt;&lt; &quot;4&quot;)"
                />
        </PackageGroup>

    </Fragment>


</Wix>
```

Comment: If you want to detect versions above 4.5, you need to use the "Release" value (instead of "Version") because it is numeric. This page shows how to use it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Here is an updated link to WIX expression syntax in condition statements: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax/